# How to transpile compiled svelte with babel for safari 9

Tags: safari, babeljs, babel-loader, svelte

Setup: webpack running svelte-loader and then babel-loader

Problem: even when other old browsers can now run the svelte code, safari 9 fails with

```
TypeError: type error
```

in the babel call to `_isNativeFunction()` on the `HTMLElement` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that svelte extends the `HTMLElement` class in some of its compiled code, and babel obviously will replace the extension of this class with
`_wrapNativeSuper(HTMLElement)` since that's not ES5.

`wrapNativeSuper` is a babel method that ends up calling `_isNativeFunction`, and `_isNativeFunction` expects to be passed a function. Unfortunately, in older safari (and only in older safari), `HTMLElement` is not a function, and so `_isNativeFunction` throws this typeError even when the code is theoretically being transpiled for use with safari 9!

The hacky solution that I've found so far is from the following circa-2015 posts about this from the safari side of things:

https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/1709

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1548

[Should I write v1 Custom Elements in a way that is backwards compatible with v0 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060163/should-i-write-v1-custom-elements-in-a-way-that-is-backwards-compatible-with-v0)

so it seems that this hack was kind of well known back in the day - basically just add a shim to allow `HTMLElement` to respond like a function:

```
if (typeof HTMLElement !== 'function'){
    var _HTMLElement = function(){};
    _HTMLElement.prototype = HTMLElement.prototype;
    HTMLElement = _HTMLElement;
}
```

I put the above code in before loading any of my frontend resources, and it worked a charm.

Further questions: Is there any danger to doing this? Is there a better way? Is this something babeljs should be taking care of as part of safari 9 support?